# Physical interpretation of a hypermomentum tensor

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-calculus

In Einstein-Cartan gravity, the metric and connection are independent objects. Therefore, a matter action coupling to gravity may imply the existence of

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta S_{matter}}{\delta \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\rho}} = \Delta^{\nu\rho}_{~~~\mu}$$

which is called the Hypermomentum tensor (if the matter couples to the connection). Is there a physical interpretation for such a tensor and its components?

Comment: Hehl et al. give it a good effort here: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/zna-1976-0201/html?lang=en